# Barra de titulo personalizada en Windows Forms

Tags: windows-forms, herencia

estoy intentando hacer un formulario base para que el resto de formularios hereden de este.
Mi propósito es sustituir la barra de título por una propia y hacerla extensible al resto de formularios.
Esta no es más que un Panel con un botón salir, pero no sé cómo debo hacer para que el panel ocupe siempre el ancho del formulario hijo y el que el botón de salir este siempre el máximo a la derecha.

Podéis guiarme por favor?
Gracias.